# Copy a Specific Row from one sheet to another based on few conditions

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I want to copy an entire row based on if one of the 4 columns that I am interested is greater than 0.  I am new to VBA and tried the following code and it does not seem to work.

```
Sub MyViewCopy()
    Set sh = Sheets("XyNewSheet")
    RowCount = 0
    lr2 = 0
    For Each rw In sh.Rows
        If (
       (Cells(rw.Row, 10).Value > 0) Or (Cells(rw.Row, 12).Value > 0) 
        Or 
       (Cells(rw.Row, 14).Value > 0) Or (Cells(rw.Row, 16).Value > 0) 
       Or 
       (Cells(rw.Row, 18).Value > 0)
       ) Then
       Rows(rw).Copy Destination:=Sheets("MyView").Range("A" & lr2 + 1)
       lr2 = Sheets("MyView").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

       RowCount = RowCount + 1
    End If
    Next rw
    MsgBox (RowCount)
End Sub
```

Comment: You understand that you are checking every row all the way to the bottom of the worksheet...?

Comment: I have a worksheet XyNewSheet and if columns, J, L, N, P, R have a value of greater than 0 then I want to copy to a new sheet "MyView".  That is what I was intending to do.

Comment: try putting `sh.` in front of all the `Cells(rw...`  and in front of `Rows(rw).copy`

Answer (score 0):

Try cutting down the rows examined to the rows with actual values in columns J, L, N, P and R.

```
Option Explicit

Sub MyViewCopy()
    Dim r As Long, rc As Long, mxr As Long

    With Worksheets("XyNewSheet")
        mxr = Application.Max(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row, _
                              .Cells(.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row, _
                              .Cells(.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row, _
                              .Cells(.Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row, _
                              .Cells(.Rows.Count, "R").End(xlUp).Row)
        For r = 1 To mxr
            If .Cells(r, "J").Value2 > 0 Or .Cells(r, "L").Value2 > 0 Or _
               .Cells(r, "N").Value2 > 0 Or .Cells(r, "P").Value2 > 0 Or _
               .Cells(r, "R").Value2 > 0 Then
                .Rows(r).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("MyView").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                rc = rc + 1
            End If
        Next r
    End With

    MsgBox (rc)
End Sub
```

Your bracketing on the Or statements was unnecessary. There are only necessary if you want to group combinations of And and Or together.

Comment: Thank you so much. This helped me !!